# Substitute a function and variable into the LaTeX string with latex2exp

Tags: r

How to substitute a variable into the string using `latex2expr`? I'm wanting to include variable `d1`'s value in the text rounded to two decimal places? The following does not work but I'm sure you will get the idea.

```
require(latex2exp)
d1 = 0.30523
plot(1, 2)
text(1, 2, TeX('d_1 = {round($d1),2)}'), cex = 4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to create the correct string first using the `paste0` function. The following code should work.

```
require(latex2exp)
d1 = 0.30523
plot(1, 2, type="n")
new_text = paste0("$d_1 = ",round(d1,2),"$")
text(1, 2, TeX(new_text), cex = 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

(This answer may not solve your question directly. I just provide another way to achieve the goal.)

I'm not familiar with the package `latex2exp`. I usually present math in a plot by the built-in syntax of `plotmath`(call `?plotmath` for more details). The base function `bquote()` can do partial substitution in expressions. It quotes its argument except that terms wrapped in `.()`.

```
d1 = 0.30523
plot(1, 2, type = "n")
text(1, 2, bquote(d[1] == .(round(d1, 2))), cex = 4)
```

By the way, the following two expressions are equivalent.

```
bquote(d[1] == .(round(d1, 2)))
substitute(d[1] == x, list(x = round(d1, 2)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you - I tried bquote() initially but could not fathom the syntax.  I found this web page which was helpful https://www.r-bloggers.com/math-notation-for-r-plot-titles-expression-and-bquote/

Comment: @Markm0705 You can call `demo(plotmath)` to search all syntax of `plotmath`.